# I am curious about the principle when downloading a file with selenium package

Tags: python, selenium

I am curious about the principle when downloading a file with selenium package.
When downloading files by calling https, do you use a port other than 443 port? Or is there another principle?

I developed a process to download a file by pressing a specific button after connecting to Google Chrome using Selenium.
This is simple code.

```
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
...
op.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'download.default_directory': some_path})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=op)
driver.get('https://some_url')
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="some_button"]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
da = Alert(driver)
da.accept()
```

And It worked well in the aws ec2 server, but when the same code was executed in the company's internal network, the file was not downloaded.
What I did was disable the 80, 443 port firewall for the url to access And access to all ports accessed from the ip of the url is possible.
Access using telnet works fine, but the file download part does not work.
There was no error logging, so I asked here. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: could just be a path issue.  Does the browser show the download start?

Comment: There was a problem with the url when downloading was different from the url I had turned off the firewall.
The site was using two different urls. I also disable the firewall for this so the download works fine. Thank you for answer.